# Can't seem to animate ng-show AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to do a fade in animation when ng-show condition is met. I can see the animation for ng-hide but not for ng-show.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/angular-animate@1.7.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/>
  <input type="button" data-ng-click="click()" value="Click"/>
  <input type="button" data-ng-click="reset()" value="Reset"/>
  <div data-ng-show="bool" class="test">
     {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test.ng-show{
  transition:1s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}
.test.ng-show.ng-show-active{
   opacity:1;
}
```

JS

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.name='';
  $scope.bool=false;
  $scope.click=function(){
    $scope.bool=true;
  };
  $scope.reset=function(){
    $scope.bool=false;
    $scope.name='';
  };
});
```

Here's a link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diggledoot/n3qh6214/3/) of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the CSS to achieve this. Click on `Toggle` button to see the better animation toggle effect.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Hello World!';
  $scope.bool = false;
  $scope.click = function() {
    $scope.bool = true;
  };
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.bool = false;
    $scope.name = '';
  };
});
```

```css
.test.ng-hide-add,
.test.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity: 1;
}
.test.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
.test{ margin-top:20px;font-size:2rem}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/angular-animate@1.7.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
  <input type="button" data-ng-click="click()" value="Click" />
  <input type="button" data-ng-click="bool = !bool" value="Toggle" />
  <input type="button" data-ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
  <div data-ng-show="bool" class="test">
    {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry if it seems dumb to ask,what does ng-hide-add and ng-hide-remove do, @palaѕн?

Comment: Those are just two class added by angular animation internally. addclass is added after the ngShow expression evaluates to a non truthy value and just before the contents are set to hidden. and remove class is added after the ngShow expression evaluates to a truthy value and just before contents are set to visible. You can learn more about the steps involved in the animation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate)